# Unity Toast аналогичные android

Tags: unity3d, toast

Только начинаю изучать Unity. До этого был опыт на Android. Необходимо сделать всплывающее окно с подсказкой. Собираться будет под Window . Есть ли в Unity что то аналогичное Toast из стандартных библиотек, который можно вызвать из любого скрипта?

Comment: Стандартной точно нет, скорее всего есть asset посмотри в ассет сторе. Можешь сам сделать, Там довольно всё просто.

Answer (score 0):

Unity может легко собрать приложение под android, однако как только Вы хотите использовать элементы и функции системы android, в документации прямо сказано - пишите плагины. В Unity Store есть готовые asset'ы, которые позволяют работать с  элементами и функциями системы android.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял нужно для Windows...
Нашел в документации Unity описание Toast, единственное что, так это для Windows Store Apps:

[Toast для windows store apps](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WSA.Toast.html)